# Stuck trying to preselect rows in data table

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm newish to building lightning components. I've tried several of the suggestions i've found here, but still seem to be stuck.  Maybe a 2nd set of eyes will help. I get both the Lists populated, it just doesnt check the box. What did I miss? TIA!

Basically, if an Id exists in the List returned from getPreselectedFiles then the matching row in the datatable should be checked.

apex

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<custom__c> getPreselectedFiles(List<Id> files) {
    System.debug('pf: ' + files);
    String parentID = '%' + files + '%';
    // Get list of files attached to current record
    return [Select File_ID__c from custom__c where name like :parentID];
}


@AuraEnabled
public static List<ContentDocument> getAttachedFiles(List<Id> files) {
    System.debug('cdl: ' + files);
    Set<Id> docIDs = new Set<Id>();
    // Get list of files attached to current record
    List<ContentDocumentLink> cdl = [select id,contentdocumentid,contentdocument.Title from contentdocumentlink where linkedentityid = :files];
    for(ContentDocumentLink cdLink:cdl){
        docIDs.add (cdLink.ContentDocumentID);
    }
    return [Select id, title,fileextension from contentdocument where id IN: docIDs];
}
```

helper

```
    fetchPreselectedList : function(component) {

    var action = component.get("c.getPreselectedFiles");
    var files = component.get("v.recordId");
    action.setParams({
        files: files
    });
    //alert(files);
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        // Getting the response state
        var state = response.getState();
        var selected = [];
        // Check if response state is success
        if(state === 'SUCCESS') {
            var files = response.getReturnValue();
            files.forEach(function(file) {
                selected.push({Id: file.File_ID__c });
            });  
            //component.set('v.preselectedRow',response.getReturnValue()); 
            component.set('v.preselectedRow', selected);  
            console.log(selected);
        }else {
            console.log('Error');
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);

},
// Function to fetch data from server called in initial loading of page
fetchFileList : function(component, event, helper) {
    var self = this;
    // Assign server method to action variable
    var action = component.get("c.getAttachedFiles");
    // Getting the account id from page
    var files = component.get("v.recordId");
    // Setting parameters for server method
    action.setParams({
        files: files
    });

    // Callback function to get the response
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        // Getting the response state
        var state = response.getState();
        // Check if response state is success
        if(state === 'SUCCESS') {
            // Getting the list of contacts from response and storing in js variable
            var contactList = response.getReturnValue();
            // Set the list attribute in component with the value returned by function
            component.set("v.data", response.getReturnValue());
            console.log(response.getReturnValue());
            component.set('v.rawData', response.getReturnValue()); 
            // trying to set the selected rows 
            //component = component.find("fileTable");                         
            // Get preselected files (tried calling within callback too)
            //self.fetchPreselectedList(component, event, helper);
       }
        else {
            // Show an alert if the state is incomplete or error
            alert('Error in getting data');
        }
    });
    // Adding the action variable to the global action queue
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

cmp

```
<aura:attribute name="data" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>    
<aura:attribute name="preselectedRow" type="List" />
<aura:attribute name="rawData" type="Object" access="PRIVATE" />
<lightning:card title="Files Attached to record">
    <!-- the container element determine the height of the datatable -->
    <div style="height: 300px">
        <lightning:datatable
                             aura:id="fileTable"
                             keyField="Id"
                             data="{! v.data }"
                             columns="{! v.columns }"
                             hideCheckboxColumn="false"
                             onrowselection="{!c.UpdateSelectedRows }"
                             selectedRows="{!v.preselectedRow}" 
                             />
    </div>
</lightning:card>
```

controller

```
    // Function called on initial page loading to get contact list from server
getRecords : function(component, event, helper) {
    // Build the columns
    component.set('v.columns', [
        {label: 'Filename', fieldName: 'Title', type: 'text', initialWidth: 300},
        {label: 'Ext', fieldName: 'fileextension', type: 'text' }                
    ]);    
    // Helper function - fetchFileList called for interaction with server
    helper.fetchPreselectedList(component, event, helper);
    helper.fetchFileList(component, event, helper);
```

Comment: I think the selectedRows attribute expects a list of key fields. You set the key field to Ids. So you have to set a list of Ids instead of a list of sObjects.

Comment: I thought I was doing that. console log shows both Lists match `I thought I was doing that. console log shows both Lists match.  This is the data `
0: {Id: "069r000000kVkMAAU", Title: "Products_01", FileExtension: "pdf"}` This is the selectedRows `0: {Id: "069r0000000kVkMAAU"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selectedRows attribute should be an Array that simply contains the key values, not objects. That would look like this:

```
var selected = files.map(file => file.File_ID__c);
// ... any other code here ... //
component.set("v.preselectedRow", selected);
```

The [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function is typically used in place of:

```
var selected = [];
files.forEach(function(file) {
    selected.push(file.File_ID__c);
});
```

Comment: Now the console log shows 'selected' in brackets ["069r0000000kVkMAAU"], but it still doesnt check the boxes in the datatable.

Comment: did you add check column for `lightning:datatable` ? if yes please update your question with all columns properly

Comment: @GigaGuy I just noticed you're getting the "preselected" list *before* you get the "files" list. This might cause problems. Try reversing the order of those two calls: `helper.fetchFileList(component, event, helper); helper.fetchPreselectedList(component, event, helper);`

Comment: @sfdcfox reversed them, still no checks.
@sdandamud1 do you mean something other than `                             hideCheckboxColumn="false"`

Comment: Looks like it was cached and just started working.  I know i reversed the order previously, so I think the map fixed it.